# Function to compare strings recursively - C++

Tags: c++, string, recursion

I have to write a function called relation that compares two strings . The problem states that I am limited to only use C++relational operators
to compare single characters.

Here is where I am so far but I just get errors.

```
char relation (const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2) {
    if(&s1[0] == "" || &s2[0] == ""){
        return '=';
    }
    else if(&s1[0] < &s2[0]){
        return '<';
    }
    else if(&s1[0] > &s2[0]){
        return '>';
    }
    else{
        std::string new_s1 = &s1.substr(1);
        std::string new_s2 = &s2.substr(1);
        return relation(s1,s2);
    }
}
```

When I run it these are the errors I get. With changing some stuff around I can get it to run but I'm assuming it goes into an infinite loop because it takes a while running and just crashes.

[image]
If I could get some help I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: oh I'm sorry, sure thing

Comment: What happened when you stepped through this code in a debugger?

Comment: Why are you using `&s1[0]` instead of just `s1[0]`? That compares the addresses, not the characters.

Comment: The recursive call should use `new_s1` and `new_s2`.

Comment: (1) Please describe your problem better than "just get errors" and "just crashes". (2) `if(&s1[0] == "" || &s2[0] == "")`, even once you get rid of the `&`s, is wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry guys I'm a bit new to this, is it the "" that is wrong? or the entire statement?

Comment: I believe I have solved it
I used 

if(s1[0] == '\0' && s2[0] == '\0')

And it now functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to take the addresses of everything. You should use `s1[0]`, not `&s1[0]`.

When you perform the recursive call, you need to use `new_s1` and `new_s2` as the arguments, not `s1` and `s2`.

Your method of testing if the strings are empty is wrong. `s1[0]` is a `char`, not a string, so you shouldn't compare it with `""`. You also report `=` if *either* of the strings is empty; they're only equal if *both* strings are empty.

```
char relation (const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2) {
    if(s1[0] == '\0' && s2[0] == '\0'){
        return '=';
    }
    else if(s1[0] < s2[0]){
        return '<';
    }
    else if(s1[0] > s2[0]){
        return '>';
    }
    else{
        std::string new_s1 = s1.substr(1);
        std::string new_s2 = s2.substr(1);
        return relation(new_s1, new_s2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've misunderstood some datatypes, and then tried some hacks to stop compiler errors.  Here's the first one.

```
if(&s1[0] == "" || &s2[0] == "")  // wrong
```

You're trying to test that the strings are empty, but instead you're obtaining a character, and then referencing it to get a `char*` which can be compared with the string literal `""`, except that the result will *ALWAYS* be false.

If you want to check for empty string, use `std::string::empty`:

```
if( s1.empty() || s2.empty() )
```

Note that the logic is incorrect.  The strings are only equal if *both* are empty, and not if only one is empty.

Similarly, here:

```
else if( &s1[0] < &s2[0] )  // wrong
```

You are doing pointer comparison, not character comparison.  This should be:

```
else if( s1[0] < s2[0] )
```

Finally, you will get a stack overflow once you fix compiler errors because you're recursing on the wrong strings and again you're taking a reference:

```
std::string new_s1 = &s1.substr(1);   // wrong
std::string new_s2 = &s2.substr(1);   // wrong
return relation(s1,s2);               // passing original instead of substring
```

Instead, this should be:

```
std::string new_s1 = s1.substr(1);
std::string new_s2 = s2.substr(1);
return relation( new_s1, new_s2 );
```

Or you could just bung it into one line using the rvalues:

```
return relation( s1.substr(1), s2.substr(1) );
```

This should be plenty to get you going.